# Search the key from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Supposing, I have this array in PHP:

```
$dictionnary = array(
    '300x250' => array(
        'size' => '100',
    ),
    '300x600' => array(
        'size' => '150',
    ),
    '728x90' => array(
        'size' => '100',
    )
);
```

How can I search in the keys (300x250, 300x600 or 728x90), if I have this:

```
$var = '728x90';
```

What I tryed:

```
array_search($var, $dictionnary);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to give feedback and/or upvotes and/or accept answers to your questions.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for a key:

```
if(isset($dictionnary[$var])) {  //or $dictionnary[$var]['size']
    echo $dictionnary[$var]['size'];
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

Shorter:

```
echo isset($dictionnary[$var]) ? $dictionnary[$var]['size'] : "No";
//or
echo isset($dictionnary[$var]['size']) ? $dictionnary[$var]['size'] : "No";

//PHP 7+
echo $dictionnary[$var]['size'] ?? "No";
```

Comment: It's spelled a **dictionary** - just ***ONE*** "n" in there!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($dictionary[$var])) {
    // do stuff
}
// or
if (array_key_exists($var, $dictionary)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = '728x90';

$dictionary = array(
    '300x250' => array(
        'size' => '100',
    ),
    '300x600' => array(
        'size' => '150',
    ),
    '728x90' => array(
        'size' => '100',
    )
);
```

**Output the data:**

```
echo $dictionary[$var]['size']; // Outputs 100.
```

**Check the key exists:**

```
if(isset($dictionary[$var])) echo 'Key exists.';
```